# How to split all import statements of a lazy loaded child component from the main bundle file in react (using webpack 4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am not sure whether the title is appropriate or not. But this is what I want to achieve -

I have created a react reusable component which will return an environment specific header. When I say environment specific, I mean, in boomerang environment, I need to use some boomerang specific packages which are not supported in other environments.

I have created two separate header components for that, one is for the boomerang environment which has some boomerang UI shell (not supported in other environments), and another component for other environments.

Now, from my CustomHeader component, I am rendering the headers based on the environment props.

```
renderDynamicHeader() {
        let {project, headerText, productName, customHeaderStyle, logoutLink, onSwitcherItemClick, headerPanel, onIconClick, logoLink, headerIcons, navigation, baseURL, features, platform, bmrgCustomIcons} = this.props;
        let {environment} = this.props;
        if(environment !== 'boomerang' && environment !== 'production' && environment !== undefined) {
            return <NonBoomerangHeader environment={environment} headertxt={headerText} selectedProject={project} productName={productName} customHeaderStyle={customHeaderStyle} logoutLink={logoutLink} onSwitcherItemClick={onSwitcherItemClick} onSwitcherItemClick={onSwitcherItemClick} headerPanel={headerPanel} onIconClick={onIconClick} logoLink={logoLink} headerIcons={headerIcons}/>
        } else {
            const BoomerangHeader = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "BoomerangHeader" */ "../BoomerangHeader/index"));
            return (
                <Suspense fallback={<NonBoomerangHeader environment={environment} headertxt={headerText} selectedProject={project} productName={productName} customHeaderStyle={customHeaderStyle} logoutLink={logoutLink} onSwitcherItemClick={onSwitcherItemClick} onSwitcherItemClick={onSwitcherItemClick} headerPanel={headerPanel} onIconClick={onIconClick} logoLink={logoLink} headerIcons={headerIcons}/>}>
                  <BoomerangHeader environment={environment} headertxt={headerText} selectedProject={project} productName={productName} customHeaderStyle={customHeaderStyle} logoutLink={logoutLink} navigation={navigation ? navigation : undefined} baseURL={baseURL? baseURL : undefined} features={features? features : undefined} platform={platform ? platform : undefined} bmrgCustomIcons={bmrgCustomIcons} onIconClick={onIconClick}/>
                </Suspense>
            );
        }
    }
```

I have this configuration in my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const {
  CleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: '',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
          },
        }],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I am doing build, the internal dependencies of the boomerang header component is getting appended/bundled in the main index.js file

This is the import statement in my BoomerangHeader.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {UIShell} from '@boomerang/carbon-addons-boomerang-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './boomerangHeader.scss';
```

And this I can see as an export statement in the dist folder's index.js file

```
(r=[{key:"renderDynamicHeader",value:function(){console.log("inside renderDynamicHeader library");var t=this.props,e=t.project,r=t.headerText,a=t.productName,l=t.customHeaderStyle,b=t.logoutLink,s=t.onSwitcherItemClick,x=t.headerPanel,d=t.onIconClick,c=t.logoLink,p=t.headerIcons,f=t.navigation,g=t.baseURL,h=t.features,_=t.platform,u=t.bmrgCustomIcons,w=this.props.environment;if("boomerang"!==w&&"production"!==w&&void 0!==w)return console.log("inside non boomerang if block"),n.a.createElement(m,{environment:w,headertxt:r,selectedProject:e,productName:a,customHeaderStyle:l,logoutLink:b,onSwitcherItemClick:s,onSwitcherItemClick:s,headerPanel:x,onIconClick:d,logoLink:c,headerIcons:p});console.log("trying to lazy load boomerang file");var v=Object(i.lazy)((function(){return o.e(0).then(o.bind(null,9))}));return console.log("successfully imported boomerang file"),console.log(v),n.a.createElement(i.Suspense,{fallback:n.a.createElement(m,{environment:w,headertxt:r,selectedProject:e,productName:a,customHeaderStyle:l,logoutLink:b,onSwitcherItemClick:s,onSwitcherItemClick:s,headerPanel:x,onIconClick:d,logoLink:c,headerIcons:p})},n.a.createElement(v,{environment:w,headertxt:r,selectedProject:e,productName:a,customHeaderStyle:l,logoutLink:b,navigation:f||void 0,baseURL:g||void 0,features:h||void 0,platform:_||void 0,bmrgCustomIcons:u,onIconClick:d}))}},{key:"render",value:function(){var t=this.renderDynamicHeader();return n.a.createElement("div",null,t)}}])&&_(e.prototype,r),a&&_(e,a),b}(i.Component)},function(t,e){t.exports=require("@boomerang/carbon-addons-boomerang-react")},function(t,e){t.exports=require("axios")}]));
```

I want this require statement to be kept separately in a different file. Because of lazy loading/ code-splitting the boomerangHeader chunk is also getting created separately, but this require statement is not getting splitted into a different file.

I tried with splitChunks plugin of webpack, but that also did not separate it from the main bundle.

Is there any possible way that we can remove this require statement from this bundle and keep it separate in some other files so that I can ignore that file while working in non boomerang environment. Or is there any way to ignore "module not found" error in the client application ?

It would be really good if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Found this article which helped me to understand how does webpack work under the hood 
https://blog.jakoblind.no/how-webpack-decides-what-to-bundle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any proper solution as to how to split the import statements from the webpack bundle into a separate file, because I guess that is how webpack works.
And I wanted to split it so that I can ignore that file based on the condition.

But It seems that ignoring the package itself in the client application solved this issue.

```
if (isnotBoomerang) {
    var newClientPlugins = [];
    newClientPlugins.push(
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/@boomerang/)
    );
    newClientPlugins.push(
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: APP_DIR + '/client/index.html',
      })
    );
    client['plugins'] = newClientPlugins;
  }
```